# PHP concatenate string with table element and execute it with exec

Tags: php, arrays, exec, concatenation

I have a problem with concatenation. I have a string with a table element and then I want to execute the resulting string with `exec` or `system` Here is an example :

```
$array_of_strings("one","two","three");

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    $new_string = "the number is : ". $array_of_strings[$i] ;
    exec('ls '.$new_string, $output); //just use any command ..
}
```

This is not working at all .. it's driving me crazy please help me .thank you all.

Comment: $array_of_strings = array("one","two","three");  What's not working ? exec ?

Answer (score 2):

you have syntax error, at:

```
$array_of_strings("one","two","three");
```

to initialize array, use:

```
$array_of_strings = array("one","two","three");
```

Comment: yes, but a string isnt it array ? now suppose $array_of_strings is an array we can access  elements by using a counter no ? so in this way why is not working in my program ?

Comment: here is the real code:
$filename="file.txt";
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}

print_r ($array);

$maxi = sizeof($array); //size of file.txt content table 
$str1 ='';
for($i = 0; $i < 3;$i++)
{

$str1='some text'.$array[$i]; // here the error apears




system('cat'. $str1) ;

Comment: i put this code to write the result in table column , it's shows empty no errors and some times when i change code little, it prints 1 into 3 columns

Comment: if you want print result of command, try: echo system('cat '.$str1);

Comment: i already did that but still not working, after removing some code so that i go closely to the problem i found that the error is in this line: $str1='some text'.$array[$i]; that's why i was asking how is the concatination should be done .. the $array[$i] is not working ..

Comment: pls, add line var_dump($array), before for loop and paste output here.

Comment: array(9) { [0]=> string(15) "a.txt " [1]=> string(15) "b.txt " [2]=> string(15) "c.txt " [3]=> string(15) "d.txt " [4]=> string(15) "e.txt " [5]=> string(15) "f.txt " [6]=> string(12) "g.txt " [7]=> string(12) "h.txt " [8]=> string(14) "i.txt" }  and below that one empty column